# apply an ID to a renderDT() in a taglist

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a dynamic interface that gets created in a huge function. The function spits out a taglist with all the input features and other stuff too. Among this is a DT table. That's all good and works fine. Now I want to be able to replaceData() in the DT, however while creating the taglist i can assign an elementID to the datatable() but the renderDT overwrites that.

If I leave out the renderDT() the table still shows but the replaceData() fails with a

> DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Invalid JSON response. 
>   For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

error message.

**Current working but really bad solution:** If I have the renderDT(), some hashed ID is created which starts "out". This can be catched in an observe() and used to create the datatableProxy() object which can then be used to replaceData(). A problem with this is that you can only have one tabel and it is terrible.

there is already an issue on DT git: https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/567 but no solution.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

 uiOutput("inputs")

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$inputs <- renderUI({
    tagList( h1("a table has no id")
            ,renderDT(datatable(mtcars,elementId = "thisDoesHaveAnID"))
            ,actionButton("replaceDataGo","Replace data go!")
            )
  })

  observeEvent(input$replaceDataGo,{
    tableid <- gsub("_.*","",names(input)[grep("out.*",names(input))][1])
    tableProxy <- dataTableProxy(tableid,session = session)
    replaceData(tableProxy,mtcars[1:input$replaceDataGo,])
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Is there any was to apply an ID maybe already in the taglist to this render?

Comment: That's the first time I see a `renderXXX` inside a `renderUI`. I'm surprised this works. Are you obliged to use a `renderUI` ? If so, do `output$table <- renderDT(......)` and replace the second element of the `tagList` with `DTOutput("table")`. If you are not forced to use a `renderUI`, move this `tagList` to `ui`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The output$table solution works if I knew which tables would be generated, but as this is a dynamically generated taglist I don't know what til be created before it does. I need to assign an ID to the taglist. 
What do you mean by moving the taglist to the ui?

Comment: You can dynamically create `output$table1`, `output$table2`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap it into a `div()`:

```r
output$inputs <- renderUI({
  tagList(h1("a table has no id"),
          div(id = "myID",
              renderDT(datatable(mtcars,elementId = "thisDoesHaveAnID"))
          ),
          actionButton("replaceDataGo","Replace data go!")
  )
})
```