# Dynamically create editable DT in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, reactive, dt

I want to create an app that has the following flow:

1. The user selects some data groups
2. Those groups become dynamic tabs, with each of those tabs containing a subset *editable* `DT` with the respective group
3. Each tab contains an additional reactive `DT` that reacts to changes in editable DataTable created in #2 (in the example below, simply multiplying numeric columns by two)

Here is an example that does #1 and #2. However, #3 does not work because the information that is normally exposed with an editable `DT` does not appear in my `input`, likely due to some scoping or order of rendering issue.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel = 
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("cars", "Pick a vehicle", rownames(mtcars), multiple = T),
        actionButton("add", "Create Tabs")
      ),
    mainPanel = 
      mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
          id = "panel"
        )
      )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  df <- tibble::rownames_to_column(mtcars, "car")
  data <- reactiveVal()
  observe({
    req(df, input$cars)
    # Step 1) split data by user input groups
    df |>
      filter(car %in% input$cars) |>
      split(~ car) |>
      data()
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    req(input$cars, data())
    
    # Step 2) Editable DT with respective group
    # Creates output$<car name>
    lapply(input$cars, \(x) { output[[x]] <- renderDT(data()[[x]], 
                                                      rownames = F,
                                                      editable = "cell",
                                                      selection = "none")
    })
    
    # Step 3) Reactive DT that responds to user changes
    # Creates output$<car name>tbl
    lapply(input$cars, \(x) { output[[paste0(x, "tbl")]] <- renderDT({
      mutate(data()[[x]], across(where(is.numeric), ~ . * 2))
      })
    })
    
    # insert dynamic tabs with data
    lapply(input$cars, \(x) {
      insertTab("panel", tabPanel(x, 
                                  DTOutput(x), # access output$<car name>
                                  br(),
                                  DTOutput(paste0(x, "tbl")) # access output$<car name>
      )
      )
    })
    # input does not contain input$<vehicle selection>_cell_edit
    print(names(input)) # [1] "cars"  "add"   "panel"
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

---

You can see in this example that upon changing `mpg` to 10, the second table does not reactively show 10*2 = 20.

Normally when you create a `DT` on the server side like `output$table <- renderDT(iris , editable = "cell")` you gain access to information stored in the `input` object ([see 2.2 DataTables Information](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html)). One of those being `input$table_cell_edit` (`input$table_` bc the assignment is `output$table <-`) that you can use to create a reactive event.

Since I need to do this dynamically, I cannot hardcode assignments in this manner. `lapply` does work to the extent that I can reference dynamically created items (see `DTOutput(...)`). However, you can see from the `print` statement that the DataTable information is not created to capture user interactions when `output` assignment is done via `lapply`.

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55864065/apply-an-id-to-a-renderdt-in-a-taglist) had a similar issue, but no response. Same with this [DT GitHub issue](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/567) that also was closed due to no response.

**Question**

So, my problem is how do I dynamically create editable `DT` in my `output` object so that I can access `input` object information about edits to create a chain of reactions?

**Answer**

In any response it would be great to see code that accomplishes 1-3 above, but also:

- Adjusts the data underlying the first table when the user edits
- Adjusts the data underlying the second table when the user edits the first table
- Provide more detail about why my code does not work (how can I access DataTables `output$<car name>` and `output$<car name>tbl`, but no `input` information is accessible?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Your code would work if you simply added the logic to handle the edits
and “didn’t worry about it.” To understand why requires some details.

You correctly note that when your observer runs, the inputs that you create
in it are not immediately reflected in the `input` object. The values in
`input` are read-only in server code. They are sent by the client-side
JavaScript at the beginning of each reactive cycle. When you call
`appendTab()` you essentially send some HTML from the server R process to the
client web browser, and ask it to be included on the page with JavaScript.
It is only in the next reactive cycle that the client-side code will have
been executed and the dynamically created `input` values have been included.

However, inputs not existing does not mean you can’t use them. The `input`
object is after all essentially a fancy list that keeps track of which keys
were requested. If a key is accessed that does not exist, you simply
get `NULL` back as with regular R lists. Importantly though, the `input`
object still registers the reactive dependency on the key, so when that
key later on is assigned a value, the contexts in which it was requested
get invalidated and everything gets updated accordingly.

You mention being able to “access” the created outputs. However, calling
`DTOutput()` does not access any data from the `output` object. It simply
creates some HTML code which the client-side JavaScript can interpret to
populate with the results sent from the R process; try just executing
`DT::DTOutput("foo")` in the console. When you assign the `DT::renderDT()`
results to the `output` object, you create the results for JS to handle.

Putting the pieces together, here’s the code for an app with the behaviours
you were looking for:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("cars", "Pick vehicles", rownames(mtcars), multiple = TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(tabsetPanel(id = "tabset"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Keep track of user-edited data
  car_datasets <- reactiveValues()

  # Create tabs for selections as needed
  observeEvent(input$cars, {
    added_cars <- setdiff(input$cars, names(car_datasets))
    lapply(added_cars, function(car) {
      # Populate initial data
      car_datasets[[car]] <- mtcars[car, ]

      # Create UI panel
      appendTab("tabset", tabPanel(
        title = car,
        DT::DTOutput(NS(car)("original")),
        DT::DTOutput(NS(car)("transformed"))
      ), select = TRUE)

      # Create outputs
      output[[NS(car)("original")]] <- DT::renderDT({
        DT::datatable(car_datasets[[car]], editable = "cell", selection = "none")
      })
      output[[NS(car)("transformed")]] <- DT::renderDT({
        dplyr::mutate_if(car_datasets[[car]], is.numeric, \(x) x * 2)
      })

      # Create observer to handle edits
      edit_input_id <- paste0(NS(car)("original"), "_cell_edit")
      observeEvent(input[[edit_input_id]], {
        car_datasets[[car]] <- DT::editData(car_datasets[[car]], input[[edit_input_id]])
      })
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: +1 thank you -- this is very interesting. Do you mind adding a bit more detail about how this reacts during an edit? You have a nested `observeEvent(input[[edit_input_id]]...)` that reacts when the first table is edited and it reacts even though the parent `observeEvent` event expression has not changed. This nested observer is also within an `lapply` so does everything within the `lapply` rerun upon an edit? Or does just `observeEvent(input[[edit_input_id]]...)` run which in turn causes `DT::renderDT` to react and reassign to `output[[NS(car)("transformed")]]`?

Comment: @LMc Calling `observeEvent()` creates a persistent observer. Often nested observers are a bad idea, because re-execution of the parent observer would also re-create any child observers, duplicating them. Here we avoid that by only running the creation code once for each `car`: we only `lapply()` over `added_cars`.

On a cell edit, only the code inside the one corresponding `input[[edit_input_id]]` observer is re-executed. And indeed that causes the corresponding `DT::renderDT()` to subsequently re-execute via the shared `car_datasets[[car]]` reactive value having been modified.

Comment: So what happens if there is a functionality where the user can remove a tab and then re-add it. Is that child observer duplicated in that case?

Comment: If implemented without care then yes that could very well happen. There would be two identical child observers and both would run the same code on an edit. You could mitigate that by destroying the child observer when you remove a tab (keep track of the return values of `observeEvent()` and call `$destroy()` on them when you remove a tab), or if the observer wouldn't need to change when the tab is re-added, just keep the original observer around and make sure not to re-create it when you show the tab again.

Comment: I made a quick Gist to showcase keeping track of and destroying nested observers. Maybe it will clarify that a bit: https://gist.github.com/mikmart/31eac2805e9670c0ac0c37652831221b

Answer (score 5):

The code below should achieve your objectives. I didn't need to do anything but add the "# APPLY EDITS" section, it looks like the necessary inputs for editing are created when a tab is opened.

I've also added `options = list(dom = "t")` in a couple places to remove clutter from the tables (this gets rid of features like "search" that you might not need for your final application, see https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom for more details), and set `rownames = F` for the modified tables. Note that without rownames, we need the `+ 1` in `input[[paste0(x, "_cell_edit")]][["col"]] + 1` to get the correct column as of DT (version 0.27).

Hope this helps! I apologize if this answer is inconsistent with usual conventions, I am new to Stack Overflow.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel = 
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("cars", "Pick a vehicle", rownames(mtcars), multiple = T),
        actionButton("add", "Create Tabs"),
        actionButton("update", "Update")
      ),
    mainPanel = 
      mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
          id = "panel"
        )
      )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  df <- tibble::rownames_to_column(mtcars, "car")
  data <- reactiveVal()
  observe({
    req(df, input$cars)
    # Step 1) split data by user input groups
    df |>
      filter(car %in% input$cars) |>
      split(~ car) |>
      data()
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    req(input$cars, data())
    
    # Step 2) Editable DT with respective group
    # Creates output$<car name>
    lapply(input$cars, \(x) { output[[x]] <- renderDT(data()[[x]], 
                                                      rownames = F,
                                                      editable = "cell",
                                                      selection = "none",
                                                      options = list(dom = "t"))
    })
    
    # Step 3) Reactive DT that responds to user changes
    # Creates output$<car name>tbl
    lapply(input$cars, \(x) { output[[paste0(x, "tbl")]] <- renderDT(rownames = F, options = list(dom = "t"), {
      mutate(data()[[x]], across(where(is.numeric), ~ . * 2))
    })
    })
    
    # insert dynamic tabs with data
    lapply(input$cars, \(x) {
      insertTab("panel", tabPanel(x, 
                                  DTOutput(x), # access output$<car name>
                                  br(),
                                  DTOutput(paste0(x, "tbl")) # access output$<car name>
      )
      )
    })
    # input does not contain input$<vehicle selection>_cell_edit
    print(names(input)) # [1] "cars"  "add"   "panel"
  })
  
  # APPLY EDITS
  observeEvent(input$update, {
    
    lapply(input$cars, \(x) {
      holder <- as.data.frame(data()[[x]])
      holder[input[[paste0(x, "_cell_edit")]][["row"]], input[[paste0(x, "_cell_edit")]][["col"]] + 1] <- input[[paste0(x, "_cell_edit")]][["value"]]
      df[which(df == holder[1, 1], arr.ind = T)[1], ] <- holder
      df <<- df
    })
    
    data(df |>
           filter(car %in% input$cars) |>
           split(~ car))
    
    print("edit saved")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: +1 this is *very* helpful and a great first answer on SO. I put a `print(names(input))` in the `observeEvent` that you added. `<car>_cell_edit` does not exist, yet you are still able to access it with `input[[paste0(x, "_cell_edit")]]`?

Comment: A follow up, when I select "Create Tabs" a second time, the print statement does show all the `<car>_cell_edit` and other DataTable information.